# XSLT if condition throwing - Required attribute 'test' is missing

Tags: html, xslt, xslt-1.0

Am writting a `XSL if` condition with `AND` `OR`. But it throwing below error

Required attribute 'test' is missing.

Please find my XSL if condition below

```
<xsl:if test= "( (price = 'Y') and !(discount == null || discount.equals('0')) )">
                <div style="font-size: 9px; vertical-align: top; width: 25%;">
                Discount: <xsl:value-of select="Discount" /> % = <xsl:value-of select="lineDiscount" /> EUR
                </div>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: XSLT `OR` condition is not `||` but `or`. There are no `==` or `equals` operators/methods in XSLT. The condition should be `discount = 'null' or discount = '0'` if you are getting a text as 'null'. You are trying to include other programming languages' syntax in XSLT. Please read some tutorials for XSLT operators.

Comment: Your code is pretty messed up, but the error message "attribute 'test' is missing" probably suggests another error elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your expression (too many to write in comments)

1. Use `or` instead `||`
2. Use `not()` instead of `!` for negation
3. Use `=` instead of `==` to do equality
4. `null` is not a concept in XSLT. You can use `not()` if you want to test if an element does not exist
5. `.equals` is not a recognised function (and if it was, you would have to do `equals(distance, '0')` anyway

The expression you probably want is this:

```
price = 'Y' and not(not(discount) or discount='0')
```

Or maybe this, assuming you want to test `discount` exists and is not "0":

```
price = 'Y' and discount != '0'
```